# How to convert an Eloquent query to Adonis lucid?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, adonis.js

So I'm rewriting a Laravel app to an Adonis app and here are my models

```js
// A customer can have multiple invoices
class Customer extends Model {
    invoices() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/Invoice');
    }

    invoiceItems() {
        return this.manyThrough('App/Models/Invoice', 'items');
    }
}

// An invoice can have multiple invoice items
class Invoice extends Model {
    items() {
        return this.hasMany('App/Models/InvoiceItem');
    }

    customer() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Customer');
    }
}

// An invoice item belongs to an invoice
class InvoiceItem extends Model {
    product() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Product');
    }

    invoice() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Invoice');
    }
}
```

I want to get the sum of invoice items price * qty and here's a sample output of my */api/customers*

```js
Customer.query()
.withCount('invoiceItems as invoice_items_total', builder => {
    builder.select(
          DB.raw('sum(price * quantity)')
    );
})
.fetch()

[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "account_no": "Solana-2",
        "type": "person",
        "first_name": "Mark",
        "middle_name": "",
        "last_name": "Soriano",
        "company_name": "",
        "address": "Solana",
        "created_at": "2019-12-08 10:22:12",
        "updated_at": "2019-12-08 10:24:09",
        "__meta__": {
            "invoice_items_total": 1, // Still returns total no. of rows instead of sum(product * quantity) ?
        }
    }
]
```

Weird thing here is instead of the value of `DB.raw('sum(price * quantity)')`, I'm still getting the total number of invoice_items  rows which is 1.

My laravel code looks like this and it works:

```php
Customer::withCount([
            'invoice_items as invoice_items_total' => function($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('sum(price * quantity)'));
            },
 ])->get();
```

This code returns the sum instead of total number of rows.

Am I missing something here? Or is that out of scope for `withCount` constraints in Adonis?

Comment: `withCount` is used to count the number of rows from the query. `withSum` is what you should use if you're summing columns together. @wobsoriano

Comment: Apparently, there is no withSum method in Adonis @olaoluwa_98

Comment: Hi, if you can't find an answer here I advise you to go to : https://forum.adonisjs.com/
Have a great day